# Record UI Test disabled in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, xcode11, xcode10.1, xcode10.2

Record `UITest` button is disabled in `Xcode`

Deleted derived data, clean the build not solving this problem 
It's working fine with `Xcode 10.1`

Is there anything i'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the full class ? Is XCTest framework imported ? Is the file in the UITest target ?

Comment: @cesarmarch Yes its is imported

Answer (score 2):

I see this a lot as well.

For starters, here is how my class looks after immediately creating the test function:

[image]

Notice the following:

- No record button available, matching OP
- The diamond indicating it is a test does not appear on the left column

I then run my tests, but stop immediately. Doing that gives me this:

[image]

1. I can now record
2. The diamond appears on the left column

You can also shut down Xcode and restart, but the above steps are faster.